# Why is retval a void** in pthread_join?

Tags: c, pthreads, pthread-join

I am having a hard time understanding why `pthread_join`'s `retval` argument is a `void**`. I have read the manpage and tried to wrap my head around it but I still cannot fully understand it. I couldn't convince myself that `retval` cannot be a `void*`. Could someone please enlighten me?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: If it was a void*, you would need to write a void through it.  What is a void?

Comment: Doesn't `void *ptr` just mean that `ptr` points to something, and that you can write anything to the address pointed to by `ptr`?

Comment: Because you pass a pointer to a `void *` variable, and the value of that variable will be set. It's kind of emulating *pass by reference* in C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you are supposed to supply the address of a `void*` to `pthread_join`.
`pthread_join` will then write the address supplied by `pthread_exit(void*)` into the variable (who's address you supplied).

Example scenario:

```
typedef struct {
    // members
} input_data;

typedef struct {
    // members
} output_data;
```

Starting thread side:

```
input_data id;
pthread_create(..., start_routine, &id);

void* start_routine(void *ptr) {
    input_data *id = ptr;
    output_data *od = malloc(sizeof *od);
    // use the input data `id`, populate the output data `od`.
    pthread_exit(od);
}
```

Joining side:

```
output_data *od;
pthread_join((void**) &od);
// use `od`
free(od);
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it work if `pthread_join` was implemented expecting a `void*` as argument? Couldn't we supply the address directly as a void*, without going through a double pointer? What would be wrong with that implementation?

Comment: @nullpoin7er It would then have an address to some data. It could not store the address of the data it's supposed to return from the thread. I added a small scenario to the answer.

Comment: I now understand what the source of my confusion was. I didn't look enough into how `pthread_exit` works, but with your example it makes perfect sense. Many thanks!

Comment: @nullpoin7er You're very welcome! Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

Simple enough. The return value of thread func supplied to `pthread_create` is `void*`; `pthread_join` is supposed to return this value to caller.

It can not return this as a function return type (because it is already returning `int` to indicate the overall status of the call). The only other way as through out parameter.

And the way C does out paramters is by using a pointer to the actual type of the parameter - i.e. if you want to do `int` as an out parameter, the type of the argument would be `int*`. If your out parameter is `void*` (because this is what you are returning from pthread func!), the type of the argument becomes `void**`.

As an exercise, you can try to write a similar code yourself - first, create a function which returns `void*` (say, `void* foo()`), and than try to write another function which would call `foo()` and communicate result back to the caller.

Answer (score 1):

The exiting thread is going to provide a pointer to some data. The pthread routines do not know what type that data has, so they receive the pointer as a `void *`.

The caller of `pthread_join` is going to receive that `void *`. Since the function return value is used for something else, the `void *` has to be received through a parameter. So the caller has to pass a pointer to where `pthread_join` will put the `void *`. That pointer is a pointer to a `void *`, which is a `void **`.

Answer (score 1):

From the manpage:

> If retval is not NULL, then pthread_join() copies the exit status of the target thread (i.e., the value that the target thread supplied to pthread_exit(3)) into the location pointed to by retval.

Let's look at the signature of `pthread_exit`.

`noreturn void pthread_exit(void *retval);`

So that means if we wanted to return an `int` from our thread it would look something like this:

```c
void* foo() {
    // ...
    int value = 255;
    pthread_exit(&value);
}
```

This works because the compiler doesn't care that it's an `int*` or a `void*`, either way it's a pointer of the same size.

Now we want to actually extract the return value of the thread using `pthread_join`.

```c
void bar() {
    pthread_t thread_id;
    int *returnValue;
    // create thread etc...

    // the original type of returnValue was an `int*` so when we pass it in
    // with "&" it's now become `int**`
    pthread_join(thread_id, &returnValue);

    printf("%d\n", *returnValue); // should print 255
}
```

In plain English `pthread_join` takes a pointer and sets it address to point at the `retval` from your thread. It's a `void**` because we need the address of the pointer to be able to set the underlying pointer to what we want.